# Optimization/LP: Choose one column from each of 10 matrices to maximize the number of shared elements

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I have been told this problem can be formulated as a linear program but I am very new to LP and cannot figure it out.

Say I have 10 integer-valued matrices, each with 100 rows and 200 columns. I would like to select one column from each matrix, such that the 10 columns I selected have the maximum number of elements **with the same value** (whatever it is) in each column at the corresponding positions.

Depending on the data, there may be no optimal solution. Also, the requirement that all 10 columns have the same value may be too strict, so I can relax the requirement that *all* columns share the same value to *at least p% of columns* share the same value.

Any ideas would be extremely appreciated!

Comment: "maximum number of elements with the same value (whatever it is) in each column at the corresponding positions" is a lot to parse.  Can you break that down into multiple sentences, or using a mathematical formula?  I don't understand what is the objective function you are trying to maximize.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the problem via mixed integer linear programming as follows.  Let $A_{ijk}$ denote the $(i,j)$ entry of matrix $k$.  Let binary decision variable $x_{jk}$ indicate whether column $j$ is selected from matrix $k$.  Let binary decision variable $y_i$ indicate whether the row $i$ is common across the selected columns.  The problem is to maximize $\sum_i y_i$ subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_j x_{jk} &=1 && \text{for all $k$} \tag1\label1 \\
y_i = 1 &\implies \sum_j A_{ijk} x_{jk} = \sum_j A_{ij1} x_{j1} &&\text{for all $i$ and $k>1$} \tag2\label2
\end{align}
Linear constraint \eqref{1} selects one column per matrix.
Indicator constraint \eqref{2} forces a common value in row $i$ if $y_i=1$.  You can linearize \eqref{2} with big-M constraints
$$-M_{ik}(1-y_i) \le \sum_j A_{ijk} x_{jk} - \sum_j A_{ij1} x_{j1} \le M_{ik}(1-y_i).$$